# Fatal error after updating to WordPress 5

Tags: fatal-error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method WP_Screen::is_block_editor() in
>   D:\Hosting\11505129\html\wp-admin\admin-header.php on line 178

I am getting this error after updating my WordPress, can't login to admin.

Comment: Do you have access to your web hosting / control panel? If so, maybe you could restore a backup or try my solution below

Answer (score 1):

### Corrupted files

If this happened during/after an update, the update may have not completed correctly. Try a manual update: https://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress#Manual_Update

### wp-config.php

Your `wp-config.php` file might be empty for some reason. See: https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php

Comment: it is still not fixing the issue. I also tried to rename the plugins folder and the active theme folder. Any other suggestion?

Comment: @SantoshAchari Okay, Did you try downloading WordPress and uploading it over your existing installation?

Comment: -I did. It did not work.

Comment: @SantoshAchari Than I do not know. You could also contact your hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

If this happened during/after an update, the update might not have completed correctly. Try a manual update: https://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress#Manual_Update

Answer (score 0):

try manual wordpress update: https://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress#Manual_Update
manual updating fixes your problem